# find the upstream 5 words of matched word in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the 5 upstream words of the found match word in a string.
Example. I hav string

> This is the most Absurd rat ever in the history

I want to search for "rat" and then get the 4 words of upstream of found "rat word

I tried using

```
re.search(r'\brat\b', " This is the most Absurd rat in the history")
```

But it gives me the space position like span(25,28), but how would i use it to get the words. If i would know the position in terms of the word, then I can simply get the 4 index up/down words.

Comment: With upstream, do you mean before `rat`? So "is the most Absurd"?

Comment: yes, thats what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
s = "This is the most Absurd rat ever in the history"
print(re.findall('^[\w\W]+(?=\srat)', s)[0].split()[-4:])
```

Output:

```
['is', 'the', 'most', 'Absurd']
```

**Edit 2:**

If you are looking for the four words that trail any occurrence of `"rat"`, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = "Some words go here rat This is the most Absurd rat final case rat"
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(s.split(), key=lambda x:x.lower() == 'rat')]
if any(a for a, _ in new_data): #to ensure that "rat" does exist in the string
  results = [new_data[i][-1][-4:] for i in range(len(new_data)-1) if new_data[i+1][0]]
  print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['Some', 'words', 'go', 'here'], ['is', 'the', 'most', 'Absurd'], ['final', 'case']]
```

Comment: @EricDuminil Thank you for clarifying. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

`(?:\S+\s){4}(?=rat\b)` might be close to what you want:

```
>>> sentence = "This is the most Absurd rat in the history"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\S+\s){4}(?=rat\b)', sentence, re.I)
['is the most Absurd ']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\S+\s){4}(?=rat\b)', "I like Bratwurst", re.I)
[]
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\S+\s){4}(?=rat\b)', "A B C D rat D E F G H rat", re.I)
['A B C D ', 'E F G H ']
```

Here's an [example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UhKTdtOq-lNsU5WQ).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since you want to find all occurrences of words before `rat`, `findall` with a more complex regex is required:

```
import re
s = 'This is the most absurd rat ever in the history of rat kind I tell you this rat is ridiculous.'
answer = [sub.split() for sub in re.findall(r'((?:\S+\s*){4})rat', s)]
# [['is', 'the', 'most', 'absurd'],
#  ['in', 'the', 'history', 'of'],
#  ['I', 'tell', 'you', 'this']]
```

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

You can just `split` the string by `rat`:

```
import re
s = 'This is the most Absurd rat ever in the history'
answer = re.split(r'\brat\b', s, 1)[0].split()[-4:]
# => ['is', 'the', 'most', 'Absurd']
```

I assume upstream meant before, if you meant after then change `[0]` to `[1]` and `[-4:]` to `[:4]`. You'll also need to add some code to check whether `rat` is even in the string at all, otherwise this will break.

Comment: what is "1" under the bracket

Comment: In the `split` method? Max times to split, in case `rat` appears multiple times. Python has [good documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) btw.

Comment: how would it work, if there multiple "rat" in the text.  I would need to extract the upstream 4 words from each occurence of "rat"

Comment: Then you would need to do it differently. You didn't specify that originally.

Comment: @user1631306 I edited my answer with a proper solution to your problem, cheers.